# SignalR hubs not registered when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, signalr, owin, signalr-hub

I have SignalR running in a web role in Azure. It has been working perfectly fine for about a year. However, after updating to VS2013 and updating all packages, it seems as if my SignalR hub is not being created when deployed to Azure. When surfing to http://mysite.cloudapp.net/signalr/hubs I get a "Value cannot be null. Parameter: key" error, and the client can also not connect.

However, it still works perfectly fine in the Azure dev fabric on my machine.

What could be wrong? I have a Startup class where SignalR is registered:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

OWIN is updated to 2.1.0.0 via NuGet.

Is there anything more I need to do to get the hubs created in the Azure production environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to re-create the web role project in Visual Studio and manually add back all of the code. A likely culprit is the web.config and how it is modified and then re-modified when updating and installing NuGet packages, although I can't be certain. But it worked perfectly when starting fresh from a new Visual Studio project (with the same code).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enable WebSockets on Azure if you didn´t do it yet.
As per asp.net site:

> Enabling WebSockets on Azure Web Sites
>
> WebSockets needs to be explicitly enabled in Azure Web Sites to be
>   used in a SignalR application; otherwise, other protocols will be used
>   (See Transports and Fallbacks for details).
>
> Note that WebSockets is only available on Basic and Standard tier
>   Azure Web Sites, and that the number of active Web Socket connections
>   is restricted for Basic tier sites. See Web Sites Pricing Details for
>   more information.
>
> In order to use WebSockets on Azure Web Sites, enable it in the
>   configuration section of the site. To do this, open your web site in
>   the Azure Management Portal, and select Configure. At the top of the
>   configuration page, ensure that .NET 4.5 is used for your web site. At
>   the bottom of the Configuration page, select Save to save your
>   changes.